# How to know what javascript function is called?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a SharePoint website with menus and everything.
I want to know what JavaScript function is called when I click an item.
How to know that? Is there any tool to trace javascript functions called? I use IE
Thanks a lot

Comment: IE version?  Open up developer tools in IE (F12).

Answer (score 2):

I know this may not be the best help as you are not a chrome/firefox user. However, if you do chose to switch over, the Google Chrome browser has a script checker built in, which catches everything that you want to console.log().

This is simular with Firefox, however, firefox you have to download the addon "fire-bug" which can do the same, but it does not come pre-installed.

IE has an inbuilt 'program' called developer tools, which could be what you want, however I believe this came in through the later stages of IE such as IE 8+ (don't quote me on that)

Comment: Additionally Chrome Dev tools allow your to set breaks on Event Listeners (side bar of scripts page) so you can step through the handles attached to that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/download.php) to inspect HTML element and also find what JavaScript function is called, then you can use Microsoft debugger, to put a breakpoint into the function and debug.